# How can I seperate reads and writes with a multi-db setup with django & postgresql?

Tags: django, postgresql, database-replication, master-slave, django-orm

as some of you are aware Django has multi-db support. This can be achieved by writing a dbrouter to send writes to the master database and all the reads to the slave, but as stated on the [Django Docs For Master/Slave Configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/)

> The master/slave configuration described is also flawed – it doesn’t provide any solution for handling replication lag (i.e., query inconsistencies introduced because of the time taken for a write to propagate to the slaves). It also doesn’t consider the interaction of transactions with the database utilization strategy.

How can I account for replication lag and the query inconsistencies due to the time it takes for the write to propagate to the slaves? Is there any sort of code I can implement for this?

Comment: are you looking to disable write on certain databases ?

Comment: @karthikr Hey, I'm just trying to make all the writes go the Master and all the reads to the slave. By doing this, I lighten the load because instead of having one database doing all the reads and writes, I have two databases that are identical sharing the work allowing everything to run smoothly and efficiently:)

Comment: oh sorry. i misunderstood your question.

Comment: @karthikr no worries :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're writing to MASTER and immediately reading from SLAVE, you will always run the risk of inconsistencies. You can mitigate the risk but you can never avoid it.

Doing everything possible to profile, tune and minimize the replication lag will help. Delaying the read query until the last possible moment will help. But it can't be avoided entirely if you're intent on *never* reading from MASTER.

If you time the replication lag under typical usage, you could configure something like [django-multidb-router](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-multidb-router#pinningmasterslaverouter) to read from MASTER for a specified period of time after write. Still is not 100% safe but you can configure it to be 99.9% safe for your setup.

Comment: Thank you perrygeo, this is exactly what I was looking for, at least this way, I have a safeguard if the user decides to quickly check the recently posted item. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Note that in MySQL 5.6 they have introduced a "Semi-Sync" mode (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-semisync.html), which guarantees a synchronous slave when used in a simple Master-slave (and only one slave) setup. This avoids that very specific problem, but what you gain in consistency you lose in some added transaction time.